# Selenium WebDriver: Wait for document.readyState

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

what's wrong here? I wanna to wait with the next task until my page is completely loaded.
Problem: No errors, but the Driver doesn't wait :-(

```
# wait for page load
wait2 = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 20) # seconds
count = 0
begin
  raise("maximum attempt crossed #{count} times") if count > 3
  wait2.until {
    self.getDriver.execute_script("return document.readyState;") == "complete"
  }
rescue Timeout::Error
  count +=1
  retry
end

#do sth
```

Comment: Did you encounter any error? If so what is that error... If not what wrong you meant?

Answer (score 0):

I would handle the issue as below :

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 20) # seconds
count = 0
begin
   raise("maximum attempt crossed #{count} times") if count > 3
   # if the page having title 'page_title' is not loaded within 20 seconds
   # time out error will be thrown,which will be handled by the rescue clause.
   wait.until { driver.title == 'page_title' }
rescue Timeout::Error
   count +=1
   retry
end
```

Comment: I actually don't now the page_title or anything else on the new page. HOw to deal with that?

Comment: @fabian I used that as an example.. But exception block is the main trick.. you can try that technique..

Comment: I've updated my initial code-block. No: No errors, but the script does not wait long enough… i always get a blank page

Comment: This is what I am trying to build: Open a Facebook Fanpage, navigate to the first "app/tab" and take a screenshot. Than move to the next app/tab etc. Problem: My app does not wait for the app/tab to be completely loaded and takes the screenshot to early => blank/white page. Here is the complete file http://pastebin.com/vYmvB4fC

Comment: @fabian Did you try to increase `:timeout => 20` to `:timeout => 40` or else? But the error gone .. right? :)

Comment: Yes i played a lot with these numbers. Here is the complete file pastebin.com/vYmvB4fC   (ignore the numbers)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40335/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-fabian)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for me.

```
DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 10

def wait_for_page_to_load(options = {})
    options[:timeout] ||= DEFAULT_TIMEOUT

    wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(options)
    wait.until {current_driver.execute_script('var browserState = document.readyState; return browserState;') == "complete" }

end
```